# customize action bar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I need to customize action bar to look like this photo

[image]
when click on image of right it opens slide menu from right of screen , that works fine
I tried that so far

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_bar));
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

action_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fb"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#00C78C" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/aslogo" />
</item>
```

and for search and setting icons i used this in main.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"

    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_help"
    android:icon="@drawable/assetting"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/assearch"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

here is what i have so far

[image]

any help please

Answer (score 1):

ok first of all .. remove your title with

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

then you should use **orderInCategory** in your xml file and it will order from less number to greater (from left side of your action bar) ...

Comment: but icon of logo which opens sliding window is not in menu.xml file  how can i move it from left to right ?

Comment: have you tried to declare it as " android:showAsAction="always" ?

Comment: the same still on left of action bar

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android's native Actionbar, proper RtL is only supported post Android 4.2: [change action bar direction to right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512504/change-action-bar-direction-to-right-to-left)

If you want to support older Android versions, you probably have to customize one of the open source actionbar libraries, and use [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) for sliding from right action.