# Android Action bar direction RTL

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I try what [simon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512504/change-action-bar-direction-to-right-to-left) tell to do for change direction but it's doesn't working.
It's seems that for hundredth of a second it's work but when Action bar add the action buttons it's put the buttons at left instead at right.

What can be the problem? it's seems that somewhere in nmy code had line that tell freamwork to do otherwise?

Comment: Check this github (https://github.com/seifolahi/android-RTL-actionbar) project

Comment: I dont use extrenal package, by android it's need to work, I wonder why it's doesn't work?

Comment: Don't use external code, but u can check there code and get an idea

Comment: create custom layout!

Comment: If i create custom layout i Will forfeit all benefits and effectiveness of action bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RTL value (true or false) is included in the flags in getApplicationInfo.flags.

As a long shot - is it possible that you are somehow changing the value?

Comment: Thank You!! someone in my team, before a long time , override in mistake the ApplicationInfo.flags value.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to set RTL was added in Android 4.2 if you are supporting this OS level or higher, this will be easier for you to accomplish.

Proof it is 4.2+: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/actionbarsherlock/-npidM2Eo0w
Google post outlining how to change to RTL: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/HuHNSb8V7s8

Otherwise, I would reference the SO question already pointed to in another comment if you are supporting an OS level older than 4.2: [How to handle RTL languages on pre 4.2 versions of Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746091/how-to-handle-rtl-languages-on-pre-4-2-versions-of-android)

Comment: I accomplish but it's dosen't work. It's seems that when the activity load the menu options' it's cause to title move left and put the buttons in right indstead