# RTL support for all API levels android

Tags: android, right-to-left

I want to enable RTL support in my android application. I have checked this question [change action bar direction to right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512504/change-action-bar-direction-to-right-to-left/17683045#17683045)

I have done the below things:

1. Added `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the `<application>` element in manifest file
2. And Added the below function in onCreate method of MainActivity.java class.

   ```
   private void forceRTLIfSupported()
   {
     if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
       getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
     }
   }
   ```

But it changes the MainActivity's layout only from LTR to RTL. Now I want to change the layout of each activity of my app, how can I do that.
Please help me in anyone has any idea about RTL support in all over the app.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a base activity and extend all your activities from it:

## BaseActivity.java

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        forceRTLIfSupported();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    private void forceRTLIfSupported()
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
            getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        }
    }

}
```

## SampleActivity.java

```
public class SampleActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
    }

}
```