# Align menu item at Navigation to the right side in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, menuitem

I made the navigation drawer at android app and make everything correctly to appear it from the right side but only I face one problem at the alignment of menu item to the right side but I couldn't , how I can do that?

The picture show navigation with menu items in the left side 
[image]

This is the main_activity layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />



<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

and this is the activity_main_drawer menu items xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Camera" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

The problem in these items I need to display it at right side not at the left side because my navigation opens from right to left

MainActivity code :

```
public class ParentMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_parent);
    /*Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);*/

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "You have chosen mail option", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ImageButton menuRight = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menuRight);



    menuRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
            } else {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
            }
        }
    });
    /*ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();*/

    NavigationView navigationView1 = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    navigationView1.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
     if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    String text = "";
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        text = "camera";
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        text = "gallery";
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        text = "slideshow";
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        text = "tools";
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        text = "share";
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
        text = "send";

    Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: @MoralesBatovski OK, I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you project is using API level 17 or higher you can add [android:supportsRtl](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) to you *manifest*.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
...
</application>
```

This attribute declares whether your application is willing to support right-to-left (RTL) layouts. If set to **true** and targetSdkVersion is set to 17 or higher, various RTL APIs will be activated and used by the system so your app can display RTL layouts. If set to false or if targetSdkVersion is set to 16 or lower, the RTL APIs will be ignored or will have no effect and your app will behave the same regardless of the layout direction associated to the user's Locale choice (your layouts will always be left-to-right).

**EDIT:**
The answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17683045/3919009) shows that exists a way to force RTL mode if it is available. In *onCreate()* method call *forceRTLIfSupported()*.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void forceRTLIfSupported() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){   
        getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }
}
```

Comment: But it depends on the system language so we don't have any other way to make this menu to the right side without depending on the system language? 

I tried your solution and it's working very good if I changed my system language

Answer (score 2):

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl" // set layoutDirection to 'rtl
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_selectcolor_imagecolor"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_selectcolor_textcolor"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"/>
```